# How to compute an analytical bound for $x$ when $x-\log x<1+\epsilon$?

Tags: calculus

Given function $f(x)=x-\log(x)$, if $x-\log(x)<1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon<1/2$, I can use mean value theorem on an interval around $1$ and have
$$1-\epsilon_1<x<1+\epsilon_2$$
where $\epsilon_1=\sqrt{\epsilon^2+4\epsilon}-\epsilon, \epsilon_2=\sqrt{\epsilon^2+4\epsilon}+\epsilon$.
However, if $\epsilon\geq 1/2$, it is hard to use mean value theorem to get a analytical bound. Here I need an analytical bound for further analysis. Is there anyone can help me?